# CMOS Logic Design

Tags: logic-gates, cmos

How to represent such an equation using CMOS inverter (The whole equation is inverted)
Z=~[(A.B)+C.(A+B)]

The load equation will be : 
[(A'+B').C'+(A'.B')]
' means it is inverted

The driver equation will be :
[(A.B)+C.(A+B)]

The problem is how am i going to use transistor A and B in parallel(OR) and in
series(AND) in one diagram ?

And how is the layout gonna be drawn ?

[image: Is this Design ok ?]

Comment: A and B represent input signals, not transistors. Obviously, each one will be connected to more than one transistor!

Comment: won't using the design shown above cause error in Euler path (repeating a signal in one path )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic circuit below is what you are trying to achieve with simple logic gates.  To bring it up further, you can find CMOS Logic circuit for each of those elements and tie the outputs together to complete your required circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2focIkR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit for a CMOS AND Gate is the following:

[image]

And the circuit for a CMOS OR Gate is the following:

[image]

You can change the logic symbol by those CMOS circuits and you should be able to get what you are looking for.  Note that you will have A and B tied together to drive one OR gate and one AND gate.  The output of the first OR gate is tied to the input of the second AND gate and C is the other input for this AND gate.  Both outputs of the AND gates are the inputs for the last OR gate that will determine output Z.